# C- Linux- Creating a thread and passing in a buffer

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

User passes in input, this input is stored in argv[2]. I store this value onto a buffer, then attempt to pass that value through my pthread_create function to another function. However, this distorts the value of the buffer.

I pass in the input, maybe something like "Hello", then when it gets printed in the "printFiles" function, it's gibberish. How do I fix this?

```
void *printFiles(void *file);

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{
    pthread_t thread;

    char *store = argv[2];

   char *buffer = (malloc(500)); 

   strcpy(buffer, store);

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, printFiles, (void *)&buffer);
    pthread_join(&thread, NULL);
return 0;


}

void *printFiles(void *file)
{
    printf("%s\n", file);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`buffer` is already a pointer. When you do this you give the thread *a pointer to a pointer* and then you handle it as just a pointer in the function:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, printFiles, (void *)&buffer);
```

Just pass the pointer to the thread:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, printFiles, (void *)buffer);
```

Comment: If the prototype for `pthread_create()` is visible, you can drop the cast entirely.